# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "The input data is not a complete block." on stream.Close()

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, cryptography

With the below code, I get the error message at `stream2.Close()`:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "The input data is not a complete block.

I searched on the internet, but no solution seems to match my program.

```
public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        byte[] salt = buffer1;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                managed.KeySize = 0x100;
                managed.BlockSize = 0x80;
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 0x3e8);
                managed.Key = bytes.GetBytes(managed.KeySize / 8);
                managed.IV = bytes.GetBytes(managed.BlockSize / 8);
                managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream((Stream)stream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    stream2.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                    stream2.Close();
                }
                buffer = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Also, **do not** derive the IV from the key! It needs to be different for every thing you encrypt.

Comment: Whoever encrypts the data should generate the IV.  You need to use the same IV on the decryptor.  You don't need to protect the IV, you can pass it around as clear-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CBC mode the input size of the ciphertext, in this case `bytesToBeDecrypted` should be a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES, irrespective of the key size). Somehow your input size is not a multiple of the block size.

However, we cannot tell why `bytesToBeDecrypted` is not a multiple of the block size, that's outside the code fragment. Usually it is either that the data is not read up to the end of the ciphertext, or that here has been an encoding / decoding mistake.